# Convert between numbered and unordered lists in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

Is there a function to convert between numbered and unordered lists in org-mode? The lists may or may not be nested.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the function `org-ctrl-c-minus`, bound by default to
(you guessed it) <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd>, to cycle through the bullet types.  The doctstring reads:

> Insert separator line in table or modify bullet status of line.
>   Also turns a plain line or a region of lines into list items.
>   Calls `org-table-insert-hline`, `org-toggle-item`, or
>   `org-cycle-list-bullet`, depending on context.

`org-cycle-list-bullet`, in turn, does the following according to
the docstring:

> `(org-cycle-list-bullet &optional WHICH)`
>
> Cycle through the different itemize/enumerate bullets.
>   This cycle the entire list level through the sequence:
>
> `-`  ->  `+`  ->  `*`  ->  `1.`  ->  `1)`
>
> If WHICH is a valid string, use that as the new bullet.  If WHICH
>   is an integer, 0 means `-`, 1 means `+` etc.  If WHICH is
>   `previous`, cycle backwards.

See the
[`org` manual node on plain lists](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html)
for more details.

Comment: It isn't `C-c--` but `C-c -`. In words: Press and hold together the two buttons _Ctrl_ and _c_, release them and press the button `-` (minus).

Answer (score 26):

In my org-mode environment, for example, the first state is as followings: unordered list.

```
- a
- b
- c
```

Modify the first line as "1. a" as numbered list.

```
1. a
- b
- c
```

Now, hit `C-c C-c` at the first line "1. a".
Unordered list becomes numbered list.

```
1. a
2. b
3. c
```

Modify the first line as "- a" as unordered list.

```
- a
2. b
3. c
```

Now Hit `C-c C-c` at the first line "- a".
Numbered list becomes unordered list.

```
- a
- b
- c
```

I hope it works.

Comment: This is awesome!

Answer (score 3):

You can use <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>

(that is `S-<right>` in Emacs notation.) This is bound to `org-shiftright`, which will automatically do the right thing for your entire list if you're on any of the items. Press it multiple times to cycle through all possible list styles. And `S-<left>` goes the other way :)

(Source: [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/5dbn1g/easier_way_to_convert_text_to_ordered_list_in_org/da3a5np/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3))

Comment: Both `C-c -` and `S-<right>` do the same thing: they both end up calling the function `org-cycle-list-bullet`. `S-<left>` calls `org-cycle-list-bullet` with an argument `previous`, something that cannot be done with `C-c -` (although that's not particularly inconvenient: the cycle is short). All of these are examples of `context-dependent` keybindings: they operate differently depending on the context. In particular, the description above applies when you use them on a list item. Consult the doc string of each function (e.g. `C-h f org-shiftright`) for details.